# Multiply ffprobe fps as value in powershell

Tags: powershell, variables, math, ffprobe

I'm trying to print the multiplied fps of a video with ffprobe,

```
.\ffprobe.exe -v error -select_streams v -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -show_entries stream=avg_frame_rate -i "$videopath" > rate 2>&1
$script:rate = [IO.File]::ReadAllText(".\rate")
$script:framerate = ($rate/2)
echo "Multiplied = "$framerate
```

What this is supposed to do is to write the fps into a file, which ffprobe does as a fraction (1/10 in this case), and then multiply it by 2.

Since the variable is read as literal text I can't multiply it by 2, and instead it just gives me this.

```
Multiplied =
1/10
1/10
```

Is there any way to make it print `Multiplied = 20` instead

Comment: Force the int data type. See the help files on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell doesn't understand fractions, so you'll need to convert the string into numbers and then do the math.

```bsh
$rate = "1/10";

# convert the string into numbers
$parts       = $rate.Split("/"); # @( "1", "10")
$numerator   = [int] $parts[0];  # 1
$denominator = [int] $parts[1];  # 10

# do the math
$framerate = $denominator * 2; # 20

write-host "Multiplied = $framerate"
# Multiplied = 20
```